# How to get a certain part of a string between key phrases (java)

Tags: java, arrays, search

So I'm making a program that grabs street names off of a website and searches them into another website, but I'm having difficulty with getting the names from the html code. So with the following code below how can I get a keyword of the string that isolates whenever a street name comes up in the html? Below is a segment of the html,

`align="left"><td>490</td><td><a href="map.php?p=texas&id=74932">Woodland Heights Cir</a></td></tr>**<tr align="left"><td>491</td><td><a href="map.php?p=texas&id=74933">Woodmoor Dr</a></td></tr><tr align="left"><td>492</td><td><a href="map.php?p=texas&id=74934">Woodmoor Ln</a></td></tr><tr align="left"><td>493</td><td><a href="map.php?p=texas&id=74935">Woodstock Dr</a></td></tr><tr align="left"><td>494</td><td><a href="map.php?p=texas&id=74936">Woodvale Ct</a></td></tr><tr align="left"><td>495</td><td><a href="map.php?p=texas&id=74937">Zermatt Ct</a></td></tr></table></div>`

and I know whenever `</a></td></tr>` happens that the street name is mentioned before it and that '>' is at the start of the street name. So I basically need to get everything between those two and add it to an array for each instance of it happening in the string.

Forgive me if this is worded a little poorly, I'm very new to java and programming in general and wouldn't know what to call something like this.

Comment: What you're doing is called "screen scraping", and there are 3rd party java libraries that help you parse the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you want quick and dirty use a pattern matcher (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html - example in docs) to match against the links something like:

```java
        String text = "...blah<a href="map.php?p=texas&id=74932">Woodland Heights Cir</a>.blah...";
        String patternString = "<a href=\"map\.php.*\">.*<\/a>"; 

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        int count = 0;
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(count));
            String[] result = matcher.group(count).split(">")[1].split("<")[0];
            count++;
        }
```

(untested but should be close enough).

More info here with examples: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html

Alternatively there are libraries like JSoup that will help with this process.

Webscraping may also be worth a look for you https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/introduction-to-web-scraping-with-java/